# EF Core Include Grandchild GenericRepository

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm using a GenericRepository to work with Eager Loading on EF Core, in this case i can loading CategoriaNutrientes but if i try to load Nutriente

```
categoriaService.FindBy((i => i.CategoriaNutrientes.Select(x=>x.Nutriente)))
```

i've got this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property expression 'i => {from
>   ManyToManyChild x in [i].ManyToManyChilds select [x].GrandChild}'
>   is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't =>
>   t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.'

```
public class Categoria:BaseEntidadeExecutora
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string NomeCategoria { get; set; }
    public Int64 QtdeMinimaRefeicao { get; set; }
    public string FormaCalculo { get; set; }
    public Int64 NecessidadeDiariaMinima { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CategoriaNutriente> CategoriaNutrientes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UnidadeEnsinoCategoria> UnidadeEnsinoCategorias { get; set; }
}

public class CategoriaNutriente : BaseEntity
{
    public Int64 IdCategoria { get; set; }
    public Categoria Categoria {get;set;}
    public Int64 IdNutriente { get; set; }
    public Nutriente Nutriente { get; set; }
    public Int64 NecessidadeNutricional { get; set; }
}

categoriaService.FindBy((i => i.CategoriaNutrientes.Select(x=>x.Nutriente)))

public IEnumerable<T> FindBy(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<T> set = entities;

    var entity = (includes.Aggregate(set, (current, include) => current.Include(include)).ToList() ?? default(ICollection<T>));
}
```

Comment: Missing code. What have you before `(i => i.ManyToManyChilds.Select(x => x.GrandChild)). ` ?

Comment: What to you mean with ManyToManyChilds? EF Core does not support many-to-many collections.

Comment: The pattern with `params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes` simply does not work for EF Core, which requires `Include` / `ThenInclude` chaining, not representable with `Expression<Func<T, object>>`.

Comment: Do you have any workaround for this step?

Comment: I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374252/how-to-write-repository-method-for-theninclude-in-ef-core-2