# How to pass lambda 'include' with multiple levels in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, include, entity-framework-core

I have a repository that gets a lambda expression for 'include'.

```
public TEntity FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includePaths)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Includes(includePaths).FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
```

In previous versions of EF I used it in services layers like:

```
var plan = _unitOfWork.PlanRepository
            .FirstOrDefault(
                p => p.Id == id, 
                include => include.PlanSolutions.Select(ps => ps.Solution)
            );
```

Where 'PlanSolutions' is a collection and the 'Solution' is a property nested from 'PlanSolution'.

But now this code gets an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The property expression 'include => {from
>   PlanSolutions ps in [include].PlanSolutions select [ps].Solution}' is
>   not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't =>
>   t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Now it seems that I can't use 'Select' method for getting multiple levels include, but I also can't use 'ThenInclude' method that Microsoft suggests, because the query by itself located inside of the repository where service doesn't have an access to. 
Is there any way to heal it?

Comment: One option that comes to mind is rewriting all `Select` to `ThenInclude` inside your `FirstOrDefault` implementation.

Comment: @Evk It would be nice. How to replace 'Select' on 'ThenInclude'? 'Select' is just a 'ICollection' and 'ThenInclude' is a 'IIncludableQueryable'

Comment: Rewriting to ThenInclude is complicated, but you can instead analyze expressions passed and convert them to path string ("PlanSolutions.Solution" for example), then call `Include("path string")`.

Comment: After some time I found a perfect solution for this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374252/how-to-write-repository-method-for-theninclude-in-ef-core-2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Entity Framework core sacrificed ease of parametrization for a more comprehensible API. Indeed, in EF6 it was much easier to pass multi-level `Include` expressions to a method. In ef-core that's virtually impossible.

But the `Include` method accepting a property path as string still exists, so if we can convert the old-style multi-level `Include` expression to a path, we can feed the path into this string-based `Include`.

Fortunately, this is exactly what happened under the hood in EF6. And since EF6 is open source, I didn't have to reinvent the wheel but could easily borrow their code to achieve what we want. The result is an extension method `AsPath` that returns a lambda expression as a property path. You can use it inside your method to convert the `includes` parameter to a sequence of strings by which you can add the `Include`s. For example, the expression ...

```
 include => include.PlanSolutions.Select(ps => ps.Solution)
```

... will be converted into `PlanSolutions.Solution`.

As said: credits to EF6 for the core part of the source. The only major modification is that my method throws exceptions in two of the most commonly attempted unsupported features: filtering and ordering an `Include`. (Still not supported in ef-core).

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static string AsPath(this LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) return null;

        var exp = expression.Body;
        string path;
        TryParsePath(exp, out path);
        return path;
    }

    // This method is a slight modification of EF6 source code
    private static bool TryParsePath(Expression expression, out string path)
    {
        path = null;
        var withoutConvert = RemoveConvert(expression);
        var memberExpression = withoutConvert as MemberExpression;
        var callExpression = withoutConvert as MethodCallExpression;

        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            var thisPart = memberExpression.Member.Name;
            string parentPart;
            if (!TryParsePath(memberExpression.Expression, out parentPart))
            {
                return false;
            }
            path = parentPart == null ? thisPart : (parentPart + "." + thisPart);
        }
        else if (callExpression != null)
        {
            if (callExpression.Method.Name == "Select"
                && callExpression.Arguments.Count == 2)
            {
                string parentPart;
                if (!TryParsePath(callExpression.Arguments[0], out parentPart))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (parentPart != null)
                {
                    var subExpression = callExpression.Arguments[1] as LambdaExpression;
                    if (subExpression != null)
                    {
                        string thisPart;
                        if (!TryParsePath(subExpression.Body, out thisPart))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (thisPart != null)
                        {
                            path = parentPart + "." + thisPart;
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (callExpression.Method.Name == "Where")
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Filtering an Include expression is not supported");
            }
            else if (callExpression.Method.Name == "OrderBy" || callExpression.Method.Name == "OrderByDescending")
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Ordering an Include expression is not supported");
            }
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Removes boxing
    private static Expression RemoveConvert(Expression expression)
    {
        while (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert
               || expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked)
        {
            expression = ((UnaryExpression)expression).Operand;
        }

        return expression;
    }
}
```

Comment: Filtering and ordering is supported now as of EF-core 5.

Comment: could you write the filter and sort with include

Comment: @TariqHajeer No, this string approach doesn't allow filtered/sorted `Include`. There's no string syntax for it.

Comment: thank you,
so how can I pass include with filter and sort ?

Comment: also in your way I can just include one path but when i have a collection and then other collection i cant pass it so how can include multiple level of collection ?

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is a bit outdated. In newer versions of Entity Framework Core you should be able to use the `ThenInclude` method as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels).

The sample for this post would become

```
var plan = _unitOfWork.PlanRepository
            .Include(x => x.PlanSolutions)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Solution)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. 
I can't thank you enough for this answer!

Comment: this still does not allow us to use a lambda expression so the accepted answer is still valid

Comment: I wonder what is "outdated" in my answer? Also, you only tell how to use `Include-ThenInclude`, but that doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

```
    public TEntity FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includePaths)
        {
DbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    var query = includePaths.Aggregate(DbSet, (current, item) => EvaluateInclude(current, item));
             return query.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
        }

    private IQueryable<T> EvaluateInclude(IQueryable<T> current, Expression<Func<T, object>> item)
                {
                    if (item.Body is MethodCallExpression)
                    {
                        var arguments = ((MethodCallExpression)item.Body).Arguments;
                        if (arguments.Count > 1)
                        {
                            var navigationPath = string.Empty;
                            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.Count; i++)
                            {
                                var arg = arguments[i];
                                var path = arg.ToString().Substring(arg.ToString().IndexOf('.') + 1);

                                navigationPath += (i > 0 ? "." : string.Empty) + path;
                            }
                            return current.Include(navigationPath);
                        }
                    }

                    return current.Include(item);
                }
```

Comment: This is perfectly working. This is all I wanted. Thankyou for sharing.

Comment: This works, thanks. Only change I had to make was in the first parameter of the Aggregate function call was changed to `DbSet.AsQueryable()`

Comment: How would you call this? say I have entity with collection and then that entity has another collection?