# Generic repository with eager load using ThenInclude() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, eager-loading

Here is my generic repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private DbContext _dbContext { get; set; }
    private DbSet<T> _dbSet { get; set; }

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        this._dbContext = context;
        this._dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> currentSet = this._dbSet;
        foreach (var item in includes)
        {
            currentSet = currentSet.Include(item);
        }
        return currentSet;
    }

    public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicated, 
        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) 
        => this.GetAll(includes).Where(predicated).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

and the problem is when I am using eager loading to load a question(include it's answers) then I can't query votes of answers.

I reliazed I got this error because I am loading a question include it's answers and include answers's vote again. So I try to using ThenInclude() to solve this problem but I have no idea how to apply it in generic repository.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First ask yourself the question whether you *really* need this repository layer. Usually it only causes trouble. Do you *really* lose anything when you remove them and work with DbSets directly?

Comment: The main reason why I adding repository implementation to my project is using dependency injection and make my code more testable.

Comment: Is it worth the imposed limitations though? Anyway, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47063432/861716) will help.

Comment: @GertArnold I am also using a generic repository for the same reason as OP. Can you please help providing some links to understand what you said in your previous comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using nested include to solve your problem. 
Reference link: [EF LINQ include multiple and nested entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764572/ef-linq-include-multiple-and-nested-entities)

Comment: This is a link-only answer, making it useless when the link breaks. Moreover, you refer to an EF6 solution which absolutely doesn't work in EF-core that OP is working in. I wonder why it was accepted.