EF 6 to EF Core migration: Expression builder for Include Statement
I'm migrating a .NET Framework project to .NET 8 which uses Entity Framework for data access.
Using EF 6, I pass my include statements into my repository as an expression, something like this:
Expression<Func<Company, object>>[] getCompaniesIncludeExpressions =
{
    e => e.Categories.Select(c => c.Projects.Select(d => d.Jobs.Select(f => f.Location))),
    e => e.CompanyUsers
}; 

and attach to the context as follows:
public async Task<List<TEntity>> SelectAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeExpressions, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereExpression)
{
    var entities = Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

    if (includeExpressions != null)
    {
        foreach (var includeExpression in includeExpressions)
        {
            entities = entities.Include(includeExpression);
        }
    }

    if (whereExpression == null) return await entities.ToListAsync();

    var list = await entities
        .Where(whereExpression).ToListAsync();

    return list;
}

I get the following exception with the above in EF Core:

AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The expression 'e.Categories.AsQueryable().Select(c => c.Projects.AsQueryable().Select(d => d.Jobs.AsQueryable().Select(f => f.Location)))' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations.

How would I refactor this to pass in the expression and include child properties using ThenInclude?
Thanks in advance

if you are changing library versions than make sure you do a clean build and with entity make sure you do a migration.

I want to be clear, did you jumping from which EF 6 to .NET 8?

Hi @jdweng. I've actually created a completely new solution for the Core application

@CrazyBaran yes EF 6 to .NET 8. Thanks

The new project must be configured differently than the old project.  The csproj file is text and can be viewed with any text editor.  I would compare the new and old csproj file to see differences.  It may be a different reference library is being used. You may want to try Net 7 since Net 8 still has bugs.

AFAIK that type of expression re-hashing translating the Select into Include does not work anymore within EF Core. EF 6's nested includes are completely different in EF Core where it uses Include + ThenInclude for nesting. The simplest re-factor would be to employ the property name approach for nesting. It's short and sweet, but relies on magic strings. (though you might be able to build it from an expression). Include("Project.Jobs.Location"). I had a quick stab at what would be involved coverting the .Select` expr to a string, but too much for a Monday.. :)

Answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374252/how-to-write-repository-method-for-theninclude-in-ef-core-2
